# Ajax Content, Second Load, Included Function Isn't Executing

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-submit, document-ready

I have a page that using ajax loaded modal dialog sub-windows.

This modal dialogs has some functions as below:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Uyelik_Formu').submit(Uyelik_Formu_SubmitFunc);
    });

    function Uyelik_Formu_SubmitFunc(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        ...
    });
    return false;
}
```

When i show modal first time everything is perfectly running. But when close modal dialog and show again, function isn't firing.

What may i do? Thanks.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console(F12->console)

Comment: Check console and give us more code, because this is not enough...

Comment: There isn't any error in the console. When second load of modal dialog, the form sends with current "action" parameters url. First load submit handler is handling process.

Comment: Krysiek the code is enough; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution myself.

The problem is submit event assigned DOM element created but when i close the modal dialog element destroyed but event isn't destroyed. I think there is a bug at this step because after this step i'm re-create and re-assign DOM element and it's event but process fails.

I've solved this with this change:

```
    $(document).on('submit','#Uyelik_Formu',function(event){Uyelik_Formu_SubmitFunc(event);});
```

Thanks.